# I am new to xslt and am trying to create a xsl stylesheet which converts an rm/cobol record layout to json

Tags: json, xslt

I have everything working except I want it laid out nicely,idented and aligned with each element/item and brackets to be on its own line except for the opening bracket of an array which is to appear on the same line as the array name as follows;

```
{
        "Components" : [
             {
                "componentid" : "ABC_CRTSW_1",
                "componentdescription" : "software ABC_CRTSW_1",
                "algorithms" : [
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_CRC32",
                                "supportsseed" : true,
                        },
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_MD5",
                                "supportsseed" : false,
                        },
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_SHA1",
                                "supportsseed" : false,
                        }
                  ]
             },
             {
                "componentid" : "CONTENT_1",
                "componentdescription" : "content 1",
                "algorithms" : [
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_CRC32",
                                "supportsseed" : true,
                        },
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_MD5",
                                "supportsseed" : false,
                        },
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_SHA1",
                                "supportsseed" : false,
                        }
                  ]
             }
       ]
}
```

The issue I am having is it is all appearing on the one line with no spaces unless they are within quotes as follows;

```
{"Components":[{"componentid":"ABC_CRTSW_1","componentdescription":"software ABC_CRTSW_1","algorithms":[{"algorithmtype":"NGI_CRC32","supportsseed":true},{"algorithmtype":"NGI_MD5","supportsseed":false},{"algorithmtype":"NGI_SHA1","supportsseed":false}]},{"componentid":"CONTENT_1","componentdescription":"content 1","algorithms":[{"algorithmtype":"NGI_CRC32","supportsseed":true},{"algorithmtype":"NGI_MD5","supportsseed":false},{"algorithmtype":"NGI_SHA1","supportsseed":false}]}]}
```

The only way I can get as I want it is if I add a non space character such as a full stop to the opening curly bracket which will give me;

```
.{
        "Components" : [
             {
                "componentid" : "ABC_CRTSW_1",
                "componentdescription" : "software ABC_CRTSW_1",
                "algorithms" : [
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_CRC32",
                                "supportsseed" : true,
                        },
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_MD5",
                                "supportsseed" : false,
                        },
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_SHA1",
                                "supportsseed" : false,
                        }
                  ]
             },
             {
                "componentid" : "CONTENT_1",
                "componentdescription" : "content 1",
                "algorithms" : [
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_CRC32",
                                "supportsseed" : true,
                        },
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_MD5",
                                "supportsseed" : false,
                        },
                        {
                                "algorithmtype" : "NGI_SHA1",
                                "supportsseed" : false,
                        }
                  ]
             }
       ]
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can avoid having to add the fullstop please?
Thanks in advance

Ok so a little more information for you;
I am not absolutely sure of what the xml looks like as I don't know how to see it - I am coding a cobol program which runs through bis and I am applying my stylesheet - here is the simplest example hope it helps clarify my situation;

COBOL COPYBOOK;

```
01  RESPONSE-TABLE4.
    03  RESPONSE-ENTRY4            OCCURS MAXIMUM-FIND-RECORDS
          30  t4componentsId                 PIC X(32)   VALUE SPACES.
          30  t4componentsType               PIC X(32)   VALUE SPACES.
          30  t4componentsRequestData        PIC X(40)   VALUE SPACES.
          30  t4componentsHostExcptn         PIC 9(2)    VALUE ZEROES.
          30  t4componentsResponseMsg        PIC X(50)   VALUE SPACES.
```

MY STYLESHEET;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="newline"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/*[node()]">{{ContentType (application/json)}}<xsl:text></xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>/{</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="detect" />
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="detect">
    <xsl:variable name="val3AsNumber" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="val3Asstring" select="name(preceding-sibling::*[1])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="val4Asstring" select="name(current())"/>
    <xsl:variable name="val5Asstring" select="name(following-sibling::*[1])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="val6Asstring" select="name(current())"/><xsl:text></xsl:text>

    <xsl:if test="name(current()) = 't4componentsid'">
        <xsl:text>"componentid" : "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>",<xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="name(current()) = 't4componentstype'">
        <xsl:text>"componenttype" : "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>",<xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="name(current()) = 't4componentsrequestdata'">
        <xsl:text>"requestdata" : "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>",<xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="name(current()) = 't4componentshostexcptn'">
        <xsl:text>"hostexception" : </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>,<xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="name(current()) = 't4componentsresponsemsg'">
        <xsl:text>"responsemessage" : "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>"<xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current())">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content1" />
            <xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*) = name(current())">,</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="(count(./child::*) > 0)"> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content2" />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*" mode="obj-content1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" mode="detect" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="obj-content2">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" mode="detect" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

MY PERCEIVED XML BEING PRODUCED BY THE COBOL PROGRAM BEFORE CONVERSION TO JSON BY THE STYLESHEET;

```
<response-table4>
    <response-entrys>
        <response-entry>
            <t4componentsId>ABC_123</t4componentsId>
            <t4componentstType>software_1</t4componentsType>
            <t4componentsRequestData>false/false/false</t4componentsId>
            <t4componentsHostException>20</t4componentsHostException>
            <t4componentsResponseMsg>No components meet search criteria</t4componentsResponseMsg>
        </response-entry>
    </response-entrys>
</response-table4>
```

MY RECEIVED OUTPUT;

```
{
    "componentid" : "",
    "componenttype" : "",
    "requestdata" : "false / false / false",
    "hostexception" : 20,
    "responsemessage" : "No Components Found For Parameters Passed Error"
}
```

HOWEVER IF I REMOVE THE TOP EXTRA /{ (WHICH I REALLY DON'T WANT) BY DELETING OR COMMENTING OUT THE FOLLOWING LINE;

```
<xsl:text>/{</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
```

I GET THIS OUTPUT;

```
{"componentid":"","componenttype":"","requestdata":"false / false / false","hostexception":20,"responsemessage":"No Components Found For Parameters Passed Error"}
```

HOPE THIS HELPS YOU TO HELP ME? 
NB:APOLOGIES FOR CAPITALIZATION ONLY USED FOR STRUCTURAL PURPOSES

Comment: You need to show a sample of the XML input data and your XSLT transformation. Also, what tool are you using for applying the XSLT? (see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to generate the JSON without worrying about layout, and then put it through an existing library of some kind that produces whatever layout you find pleasing? (There doesn't seem to be one universal set of JSON formatting rules that everyone likes.)